# Application using akka deployed in a weblogic cluster

Tags: java, weblogic, cluster-computing, akka

I am currently developping an application which will be deployed in a weblogic application server cluster. This application is consuming some JMS messages through a MDB and process some business logic through AKKA actors.

Some of these agents are singleton and others are grouped in a pool and contact through a round-robin router.

I am trying to figure out how all these things will work in a clustered environment:

- Is it possible to create a "unique" AKKA system even if the application is deployed on several nodes in the cluster? Do agents created on each server will known each other?
- It it possible to add new weblogic node in the cluster and have AKKA framework recognize these new resources?
- How configure all these things?

For what i see in AKKA documentation about the cluster implementation, it seems that the architecture supported is outside an application server, with AKKA nodes started from a java shell command.

Sadly, i have not found any valuable information on the use of AKKA in a application server environment.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say Akka agents, you mean actors? Also, I assume that round-robin dispatcher is a RoundRobinRouter :)

Akka does not have explicit support for application servers, but you should be able to instantiate an ActorSystem in your code.

As for "uniqueness", if you use clustering, the membership is maintained automatically for you so you can see which nodes are available, and you can add nodes easily. There is currently no naming service implemented on top of that, that is the target of a later version, so you have to take care of finding an actor inside the cluster yourself, or handling singletons global to the cluster.

I recommend reading the relevant sections in the documentation how you can set up and configure your cluster.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/cluster/index.html

Comment: yes you are right. sorry for using the wrong words ;)
maybe i should try first to deploy a really simple system in a cluster and see the result.